# Laravel: Making storage work on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel-4, google-cloud-storage

I followed the [Getting started with Laravel on PHP for App Engine](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/?PageSpeed=noscript) and I'm getting an error when I change the path of the Storage to Google Cloud Storage in **local development**.

ex.

```
const BUCKET_NAME = "bucket-name";
$storage_path = "gs://" . BUCKET_NAME . "/storage";
```

Here is the ErrorException:

```
file_put_contents(/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is a permissions issue that can occur when the webserver does not have write permissions to the storage directory.

Comment: I'm using the App Engine launcher, have set full_write permissions to the bucket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App Engine doesn't allow you to write to the local filesystem for security and scalability reasons. Fortunately though you can read and write to Google Cloud Storage easily using commands like `file_put_contents()`. This facility is also emulated in the local dev_appserver.

Take a look at https://github.com/ajessup/laravel for a version of Laravel that's been tweaked to run well on Google App Engine, including writing `/meta/services.json` to GCS.

Comment: Puting ``/meta/services.json`` to GCS makes each request 3-4s.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.
http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=9341
"By defining the manifest path in app/config/app.php to point to a Cloud Storage path instead, like this: 'manifest' => 'gs://yourbucketname' .'/meta',"

Looks like storage_path() issue when 'manifest' => storage_path().'/meta',